# What is the correct approach to setting and accessing global property across ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

In my model I have built an API class that creates a function for a basic API call to http://openweathermap.org/api that returns a closure with the JSON output as a dictionary.

I then call this function in my first ViewController which successfully returns the output as a string when I run println().

The issue I am having is how to store this output (all basic string types) as a globally accessible variable which I can then pass through a Segue to a custom SearchResultViewController view.

My current approach that isn't working attempts to set an empty string at the start of my FirstViewController, optionally unwrap the output as a string, store in a cityName variable and then pass that through as part of the Segue by overriding the prepareForSegue function.

I would then create the corresponding property cityName in my SearchResultViewController.

I have thoroughly checked naming conventions/linking to custom ViewController classes and want to confirm if I am missing a key step in this approach.

Detailed code below.

FirstViewController:

```
var cityName = ""

@IBAction func searchButton() {
    let api = API()
    api.weatherSearch(urlSearch: searchField.text!) { dictionary in
        println(dictionary)
        if var cityName = dictionary["name"] as? String {
                println(cityName)
        }
    }
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Search", sender: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if(segue.identifier == "Search") {
        var SearchResult = segue!.destinationViewController as SearchResultViewController;
        SearchResult.cityName = cityName
    }
}
```

SearchResultViewController:

```
class SearchResultViewController: UIViewController {

  var cityName: String!

  @IBOutlet weak var Picture: UILabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println(cityName)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `searchButton()`

```
@IBAction func searchButton() {
    let api = API()
    api.weatherSearch(urlSearch: searchField.text!) { dictionary in
        println(dictionary)
        if var cityName = dictionary["name"] as? String {
           println(cityName)
           self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Search", sender: nil)
        }
    }   
}
```

If this works then the reason your approach doesn't work is that network request is usually asynchronous

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, conceptually it makes sense - unfortunately when I ran this I got the following new error - "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'". I think this happened when it hit println(cityName) in the SearchResultViewController.
Also, appreciating it is a broad question, what is best practice to handle asynchronicity in this case? Can you point to any good resources on this?

Answer (score 0):

There are some logic mismatch here, first you don't need to assign cityName to a empty string in ViewController, you can make it an optional string. Check it with `if let` closure instead of `if var`.

```
var cityName:String?

@IBAction func searchButton() {
    let api = API()
    api.weatherSearch(urlSearch: searchField.text!) { dictionary in
        println(dictionary)
        if let value = dictionary["name"] as? String {
            self.cityName = value
        }
    }
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Search", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

     if(segue.identifier == "Search") {
        var SearchResult = segue!.destinationViewController as SearchResultViewController;
        SearchResult.cityName = cityName
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for proposal - it makes sense that some of the logic I was missing was around actually storing the optional value in a property of self. 
Unfortunately I now just get a 'nil' when I println(cityName) in my SearchResultViewController. This actually outputs in the debugger above the println(dictionary) output which would suggest to me that issue is still with the asychronicity as per suggestion above. Also why do you need to change the sender to 'self' from 'nil' in the performSegueWithIdentifier?